# Find a similar image among saved images with Cognitive services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, image-recognition, vision-api

Is there an API I can use in Cognitive Services vision API that compares images? Sometimes we import products from two brands who both have bought the product from the same seller but changed product id with their own product information. I would like to save all images with some meta-data and then be able to upload an image->compare it to the stored images and get a resultset with images that look like the ones I have uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

In the Cognitive Services family, you will find `Bing Visual Search` that will provide methods allowing to search for similarity.

Have a look to the `visuallySimilarProducts` items. But it looks like it is running similarity with public items, not with a dedicated dataset.

Public main page with a few samples: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/

REST API Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-images-api-v7-reference

Comment: That is exaclty the functionality I wanted but after som additional investigation I can see it is not available in Azure Cognitive services for my purpose of runnign it against ourown dataset.

Comment: For your information, I heard from Microsoft that a private preview may be coming soon, so there is a chance that a "public" preview will come in a few months

Comment: @NicolasR any update on this, did the facility to compare to a dedicated dataset ever materialise?

Comment: Hi @tomRedox , as far as I know (latest news in September) they were working on an integration with Azure Cognitive Search but I have no timeline

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not available in Azure cognitive services.